# Нужна помощь с запросом SQL(select)

Tags: sql, запрос

Сейчас код выдаёт всех пользователей, которые написали первый пост в ноябрь 2018

```
select top 10000 p.OwnerUserId
from (
select OwnerUserId
from posts p
where OwnerUserId in (
SELECT distinct p1.OwnerUserId
FROM posts p1
GROUP BY p1.OwnerUserId
HAVING year(min(p1.CreationDate))=2018 AND month(min(p1.CreationDate))=11

)
GROUP BY OwnerUserId) f, posts p
```

Не знаю что и куда нужно добавить чтобы он убрал людей, которые не писали ничего в ноябре 2019

Comment: СУБД укажите, да... и версию тоже.

Comment: @Akina Похоже, что это запрос к базе StackExchange https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А автор об этом знает?

Comment: да, запрос к базе StackExchange